# Any way to know if Google's noCAPTCHA reCAPTCHA fallback occurs?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, recaptcha

I'm currently using noCAPTCHA reCAPTCHA and because of how the container of the reCAPTCHA is designed if fallback occurs errors appear. I was wondering if there is anyway to figure out if fallback occurs either throw javascript, programatically (I'm using VB.NET), or other means.

Below is noCAPTCHA without fallback :

[image: noCAPTCHA]

and with fallback:

[image: noCAPTCHA Fallback]

Comment: You need to look at getting the response back from `POST`. You can also pull it from the query string... `Dim myParamValue as String = Request.Form("response")`

Comment: @436f6465786572 Is it possible to know if fallback occurs _before_ the user is filling out the CAPTCHA?

Comment: No that's the purpose of the fallback and you will not know anything until it's filled out and you get the response back from `POST` and you can get that from the `response` variable(key)  as mentioned in my first comment. You can verify more here **https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify**